# I'm trying to ask the user to input a list of 5 words and reprint them is MIPS using Qtspim but the output gives me 5 lines of "|"

Tags: assembly, mips, spim

```
.data


    N: .space 100
    arr: .space 5
    iMsg: .asciiz "Enter a series of 5 formulae: \n"   
    oMsg: .asciiz "The values are: \n"
    cr: .asciiz "\n"

.text

main:


    # ouput the prompt
        li $v0,4
        la $a0,iMsg
        syscall

        #Get input words 
        la $s0,arr 
        li $s1,0 #Counter 
        li $s2,5 #Maximum number of words allowed  to be inputted 


    loop1:
        # get the string
        li $v0,8
        la $a0,N
        li $a1,100
        syscall
        sw $v0,0($s0)
        addi $s1,$s1,1
        beq $s1,$s2,end1
        addi $s0,$s0,4
        b loop1

    end1:
        sw $s2,N


# output the string prefix text

    li $v0,4
    la $a0,oMsg
    syscall


    #Output list
    la $s0,arr
    lw $s1,N


    # output the number
loop2:
    beqz $s1,end2
    lw $a0,0($s0)
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,N
    syscall 
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,cr
    syscall
    subu $s0,$s0,-4
    subu $s1,$s1,1
    b loop2

end2:
    # exit   
    jr $ra
```

Comment: syscall 8 [doesn't return anything](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/secondyear/spim/node8.html), so I'm not sure what you intended `sw $v0,0($s0)` to do.

Comment: It's supposed to store the value in the directory v0 into the array s0. I have similar code using integers but i can't seem to get it right for string values.